# mysql select distinct where in multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql

Consider a table, zGameParticipants with these two columns and values

```
GameID | ParticipantID
1      | 10
1      | 11
2      | 11
2      | 12
3      | 13
3      | 14
3      | 15
```

I would like to select e.g the distinct GameID that has ParticipantID 10 AND 11. For obvious reasons I cannot just do like this

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT GameID
FROM zGameParticipants
WHERE ParticipantID IN ($ParticipantIDs)
```

where `$ParticipantIDs` is an array with ParticipantIDs.

There can be n ParticipantIDs, so adding n ParticipantID to an array and bind as parameters may work somehow. Otherwise a nested select may be what I am looking for, but I can't get my head around this.

Comment: can you post what $ParticipantIDs is? like what it actually looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if all you want is a unique game no matter the number of participants... aka 1 row per game

then just add `GROUP BY GameID`

this is assuming that $ParticipantIDs is a comma separated list like this

```
SELECT GameID
FROM zGameParticipants
WHERE ParticipantID IN (13,14,15)
GROUP BY GameID
```

if you dont know how to make it a comma separated list then use implode in php like this

```
$commaList = implode(', ', $ParticipantIDs);
```

then you can put it in your query

```
SELECT GameID
FROM zGameParticipants
WHERE ParticipantID IN ($commaList)
GROUP BY GameID
```

I would recommend you look into making it a parameterized query and you bind the parameter into the IN() statement

### EDIT:

from your comments it seems like you want all of the participants to be in a game for that row to be returned. to do this you can just do something like this

```
$counter = count($ParticipantIDs);
$commaList = implode(', ', $ParticipantIDs);

SELECT GameID
FROM zGameParticipants
WHERE ParticipantID IN ($commaList)
GROUP BY GameID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ParticipantID) = $counter
```

Comment: @Jake yes? what about that query?

Comment: Lets say I select WHERE ParticipantID IN (10, 11), then it will return both 1 and 2. I would like it to return only 1. Am i missing something?

Comment: @Jake see my answer or add HAVING with count ( you will get only 1).

Comment: @Jake the issue is participant 11 is a part of both games 1 and 2 so the result will be 1 and 2. are you only wanting one game returned?

Comment: @Jake see the last edit I put in. you need to count each DISTINCT participant for a specific game id and then also count the length of the array to compare it with. I added an example of how to do that

Comment: @John Ruddell do you really understand how IN+GROUP BY works? And why did I add `HAVING` ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @John Ruddell

*Example*

> **Input params**:  ParticipantID in range (13,14,15)

```
SELECT GameID
FROM zGameParticipants
WHERE ParticipantID IN (13,14,15)
GROUP BY GameID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ParticipantID) = 3 // here count of ParticipantID`s range
```

I added `HAVING=3`,because it guarantees that GameID has 13 AND 14 AND 15.

Comment: because you aren't accounting for duplicates

Comment: @John Ruddell do you really understand how `IN+GROUP BY` works?

Comment: yes. yes I do. not to sound rude but please dont patronize me. imagine having a duplicate record for a specific game. lets say the person played that game twice. this would make your query not work.

Comment: here look at [**THIS FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bae7d/1) notice how `GameID` 2 is there even though there is only one player.

Comment: @@John Ruddell Sorry,I am not rude:( But, see sentence: " `distinct` GameID that has ParticipantID 10 `AND` 11". How I see: ALL Game ids that each has AND ParticipantID=10 AND ParticipantID 11.

Comment: just look at the schema in the fiddle i added... game id 2 has participant id 11 twice (when 11 playes the game twice).. the count wont work in that case. just as a note incase you want to include it in your query for other passers by

Comment: @John Ruddell hmmm.. you about `IN (10,11,11)`?:)

Comment: @John Ruddell it hasn`t sense with `IN`.

Comment: no. IN(10,11) will match any 10 or 11. count() without distinct will count every duplicated record. GROUP BY will combine the duplicated records into a count giving the wrong result :)... just add DISTINCT so its a correct answer since the OP decided to accept yours. I don't want other people to come by and get the wrong answer.

Comment: @John Ruddell I thinking, in real, there must be index on couple(GameID,ParticipantID). And situation 10,10,11 just impossilbe(logically). Thanks!)

Comment: voodoo you can never assume something like that. I can't tell you how many times I've seen this and much worse. and most people don't even know about composite keys

Comment: John yes,of course. I just was looking at field names.. And there must be unique index on couple.

Comment: I'll throw you a +1 since you have the correct answer in there too :)

Comment: @John Ruddell ahahahahah)) Ok

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the GameIDs that have **ALL** the participants listed in the array. (And that is why you can't use the SQL query that you posted because that would select the GameIDs that have **ANY** of the participants)

If that is the case, one of the ways to solve this would be to generate your query dynamically.

```
$ParticipantIDs = array(10,11,12,13,14,15);
$selectClause = "SELECT 
DISTINCT Table0.GameID\n";
$joinClauses = "";
$whereClauses = "WHERE\n";
$i = 0;
foreach($ParticipantIDs as $participantID)
{
    if ($i == 0)
    {
        $joinClauses .= "FROM zGameParticipants AS Table$i\n";
    }
    else
    {
        $joinClauses .= "INNER JOIN zGameParticipants AS Table$i ON Table".($i-1).".GameID = Table".$i.".GameID\n";
    }

    $whereClauses .= "Table$i.ParticipantID = $participantID\n";

    $i++;
}
print $selectClause.$joinClauses.$whereClauses;
```

This generates this query:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT Table0.GameID
FROM zGameParticipants AS Table0
INNER JOIN zGameParticipants AS Table1 ON Table0.GameID = Table1.GameID
INNER JOIN zGameParticipants AS Table2 ON Table1.GameID = Table2.GameID
INNER JOIN zGameParticipants AS Table3 ON Table2.GameID = Table3.GameID
INNER JOIN zGameParticipants AS Table4 ON Table3.GameID = Table4.GameID
INNER JOIN zGameParticipants AS Table5 ON Table4.GameID = Table5.GameID
WHERE
Table0.ParticipantID = 10
Table1.ParticipantID = 11
Table2.ParticipantID = 12
Table3.ParticipantID = 13
Table4.ParticipantID = 14
Table5.ParticipantID = 15
```